# Allow text to wrap in css menu

Tags: css, menu, css-float

I have a template that uses an unordered list to create the menu. [See here](http://www.appledore-cottage.co.uk/)

When I translate the website using Google translate the menu breaks if the translations are too long, causing the floated list items to drop down. Translating it into French seem to cause the problem.

[See here](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=en&tl=fr&u=http://www.appledore-cottage.co.uk/&act=url)

Is there a way I can force the text to wrap if it is too long for the menu?

I don't mind if I have to change the unordered list to something else, but I would prefer not to use a table.

Comment: What do you want to happen? There simply isn't enough space to fit the text. What would a solution look like?

Comment: I would like the text for each menu item to wrap on to a new line and automatically increase the height of the menu.

Comment: Do you need this to work in IE7?

Comment: Yes, I need it to work in all versions of IE from IE6 onwards

Comment: Is it acceptable if it works in all browsers, but it only works in IE6/7 when JavaScript is enabled? I have a solution that looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/kH4Tj.png

Comment: Yes, that would acceptable. Your solution looks ideal.

Comment: @paul - try   word-wrap: break-word;
..............

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the words to break, I just want to wrap the text where their is more than one word, but only if the text is too long. Like thirtydot's solution - [http://i.imgur.com/kH4Tj.png](http://i.imgur.com/kH4Tj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short version: we're going to use `display: table-cell`.

The long version is.. long:

- On `.access`, remove the `padding` rule.
- On `.sf-menu`, remove `float: left` and add `display: table`.
- On `.sf-menu li`, remove `float: left` and add `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`.
- On `#header` and `#footer`, add `position: relative`.
- On `.access`, remove `height: 32px` and `margin-top: -32px` and add `position: absolute` and `width: 100%`.
- On `#header .access`, add `bottom: 0`.
- Move the `border-left` from `sf-menu a` to `sf-menu li`.
- Change the selector `.sf-menu a.first` to `.sf-menu .first`.
- This part isn't great, but to get back that `20px` `padding` on the left (and right), add an extra `li` at the start: `<li class="noHover" style="width: 20px; border-left: 0">&nbsp;</li>`; and at the end: `<li class="noHover" style="width: 20px; border-left: 0">&nbsp;</li>`. You might not need the `&nbsp;`s. You'll need to do the same thing with `#footer`.
- To stop the `:hover` on the "padding" `li`s, add something like this:

  ```
  .sf-menu li.noHover:hover {
      background: none !important
  }
  ```
- On `#footer`, add `padding-top: 48px`.

That's everything (unless I screwed up somewhere), *except* for IE6/7 support. If you want that, you're going to have to put a new version up with my fixes applied (can be in a temporary new folder if you like). It's too much work to attempt to fix IE6/7 when I have to apply all those changes first to test it properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try this and come back to you.

Comment: Getting there. I assume I need to move the html for .access menu inside the header-image div?

Comment: Ignore that last comment. It turns out I had made a mistake.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It works a treat! I have applied the fixes. The only thing I had to do in addition to your instructions was add #footer .access { top: 0; } . 

At the moment the left border is still showing, but I think that's because I need to move the .first selector to the li instead of the a tag.

Now we just need to get it working in IE6/7.

Comment: I have an idea how to fix it. Read the last paragraph of my answer again - I need you to put up the fixed version so far in a temporary folder, so I can test with IE7/6.

Comment: Thanks. The fixed version is there already. Sorry, I obviously didn't make that clear in my last comment.

Comment: Add `#header { zoom: 1 }` and `.sf-menu li { *float: left }`. Doing that makes it look acceptable in IE6/IE7 again. For the percentage of users who are using IE6/IE7 *and* looking at the site translated into another language, it's just not worth spending more time on it - especially as it's a UK based site. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, I think that will be fine. What does zoom: 1 do?

Comment: It's a common method to provide what's known as [`hasLayout`](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) in IE. In this case without `zoom: 1`, the header is screwed in IE7.

Answer (score 1):

use [word-wrap](http://www.handycss.com/wiki/word-wrap/) property of css

word-wrap: break-word;

Answer (score 0):

@Pranay pointed to the right direction but you need to set the width to the `li`s not the `ul`! so for example:

```
ul.sf-menu li {
   width: 80px; /* make this the maximum width possible! */
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**And** insert a clearing div right after the menu `ul`:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Where the `clear` class is defined as:

```
.clear {
   clear: both;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. This is close, but not ideal. I don't really want to fix the width of the list items, because that will mean that sometimes the text will wrap when it doesn't need to i.e. there would have been enough space for all the menu items, but because the width is fixed it wraps the text.

Comment: I understand your point, unfortunately I don't have a solution for this at hand...