# Superfish Menu - Change CSS to allow unlimited text

Tags: css, superfish

I am trying to change the CSS on a superfish menu to allow for unlimited text in any menu item.

I had some help with this in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620362/allow-text-to-wrap-in-css-menu) where it was suggested that I use display: table.

This works a treat for the top level menu, but the drop down menus don't line up properly.

See test bed for and example - [test bed](http://testbed.webreactive.co.uk/superfish/example.html)

When you hover over any of the menu items with the arrow the drop down menu appears on the left rather than under the menu item.

Does anybody have any idea how I can line them up?

Answer (score 0):

If the table approach doesn't work for you, you need to recalculate the top offset of your ul dropdown.

I would try with some javascript.

Something like if my `li` is higher than top offset of `ul` set top offset of `ul` to height of `li`.

Unfortunately don't have time to setup whole superfish on jsfiddle to paly around.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll have a go at this, but off the top of my head I wouldn't know where to start. In the meantime if anybody can share an example or provide another solution that would be very much appreciated.